# I'm using pandas dataframe and I need to convert an entire column of epoch time stamps to human time without using a loop

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, epoch

Currently i am using for loop which takes a lot of time :

```
for i in range (0,len(df)):
    df['time1[i]']=(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(df.time[i])))
```

Can someone suggest a way to do it without a loop and faster?

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: time respt bytes
0  1514772306.266     0   396
1  1514772306.806     0   393
2  1514772306.808     0   393

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `pd.to_datetime` with `unit = 'ms'` if you have other unit of time like seconds, minute, you can assign in unit section.

```
time
1527910027791
1527911500516

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='ms')
print(df)

2018-06-02 03:27:07.791
2018-06-02 03:51:40.516
```

And if your timestamp is in UTC, then you can simply convert to your localtime

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit= 'ms').dt.tz_localize('utc') \
    .dt.tz_convert(tz='USE YOUR TIME ZONE HERE').apply \
    (lambda x: datetime.replace(x, tzinfo=None))
```

if needed info like GMT + some hours, then you can ignore the code that use `apply` and `lambda` from above